# Android Jetty Framework: "Parse Error: Unsupported class file version 52.0"

Tags: android, import

I am working on an android application in android studio as a university project. We have just started android developement this week so I quite new to it.

We have the following error when we try to compile our app:

> Error:PARSE ERROR:
>   Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
>   Error:...while parsing org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/AbstractConfiguration.class
>   Error:1 error; aborting
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

It sounds like it's a problem with on of our libarys but we couldn't figure it out. So I created a completly new app with just the "Hello World" label in it.
I imported the GSON Library then and everything is still working. I didnt change anything in the app and just kept the "Hello World" stuff so it is a completly new app. But as soon as I import the Jetty libarys I get this error so it must be a problem with the library!

What is that problem and how can I fix it?